# Create a variable with jQuery based off the value of a class' HTML value and then passing that variable elsewhere

Tags: jquery

I'm attempting to do the following.  I need to "grab" the value found in a specific list item, then assign it to a variable name, and then use that variable in a few other places in the code.

Here's what I'm trying to do specifically line by line.  I need to get the Category value from the following list item.

```
<li class="fc_cart_item_option fc_cart_category_code">Category: SHIP6</li>
```

In this case the value I'm trying to get is "SHIP6".  The values will be either "SHIP1" through "SHIP9" (i.e. SHIP1, SHIP2, SHIP3, etc. up to SHIP9) and that's it.  Then if the value is equal to "SHIP1", I need to assign a value to a variable (I'm assuming).  If the value is "SHIP1", I'd like to have the variable equal to "1.00", if "SHIP2", the variable's value "2.00", if "SHIP3", the variable's value "3.00", and so on up to 9.  If I don't need to store it as a variable, please let me know.  But at this point I'm assuming I do.  So for the sake of this discussion, we'll call it "variable_category_ship".  So now that we've assigned the value to this variable (variable_category_ship), I need to then do the following.

Further down in the code I have this line of jQuery:

```
$('#fc_cart_foot_total').before("<tr id='fc_cart_foot_tax'><td class='fc_col1' colspan='2'>Sales Tax:</td><td class='fc_col2'>$0.00</td></tr><tr id='fc_cart_foot_shipping'><td class='fc_col1' colspan='2'>Shipping:</td><td class='fc_col2'>$4.00</td></tr>");
```

I need to replace "4.00" with the variable amount we create from above.  So I'm imagining it will now be the following:

```
    $('#fc_cart_foot_total').before("<tr id='fc_cart_foot_tax'><td class='fc_col1' colspan='2'>Sales Tax:</td><td class='fc_col2'>$0.00</td></tr><tr id='fc_cart_foot_shipping'><td class='fc_col1' colspan='2'>Shipping:</td><td class='fc_col2'>$(variable_category_ship)</td></tr>");
```

So to confirm, if:

```
<li class="fc_cart_item_option fc_cart_category_code">Category: SHIP5</li>
```

Then:

```
$('#fc_cart_foot_total').before("<tr id='fc_cart_foot_tax'><td class='fc_col1' colspan='2'>Sales Tax:</td><td class='fc_col2'>$0.00</td></tr><tr id='fc_cart_foot_shipping'><td class='fc_col1' colspan='2'>Shipping:</td><td class='fc_col2'>$5.00</td></tr>");
```

How would I go about doing this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var val = $("li.fc_cart_category_code").text();
val = "$" + val.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "") + ".00";
$('#fc_cart_foot_total').before("<tr id='fc_cart_foot_tax'><td class='fc_col1' colspan='2'>Sales Tax:</td><td class='fc_col2'>$0.00</td></tr><tr id='fc_cart_foot_shipping'><td class='fc_col1' colspan='2'>Shipping:</td><td class='fc_col2'>" + val + "</td></tr>");
```

Comment: Hey Cybernate, thanks for your response.  I did find 1 small error in your code.  At the end you have " + val + ... you start with an open quotation before + val + but never closed it.  I tried both closing it with another apostrophe after and also tried removing it.  In both cases it didn't work.  When I closed it with an apostrophe, I get this value as the result: $ Category: SHIP6.00  ... any ideas?

Comment: @flink777: Updated the post with minor changes. Try it now. It should work.